# Confusion about the proof of Theorem 3.28. in Brezis's Functional Analysis

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, separable-spaces, weak-topology

I'm reading the proof of *Theorem 3.28.* in Brezis's Functional Analysis.

---

> **Theorem 3.28.** Let $E$ be a Banach space.  If $B_{E^{\star}}$ is metrizable in $\sigma\left(E^{\star}, E\right)$, then $E$ is separable.

**Proof:** Suppose $B_{E^{\star}}$ is metrizable in $\sigma\left(E^{\star}, E\right)$ and let us prove that $E$ is separable. Set
$$
U_n=\left\{f \in B_{E^{\star}} ; d(f, 0)<1 / n\right\}
$$

and let $V_n$ be a neighborhood of $0$ in $\sigma\left(E^{\star}, E\right)$ such that $V_n \subset U_n$. We may assume that $V_n$ has the form
$$
V_n=\left\{f \in B_{E^{\star}} ; |\langle f, x\rangle|<\varepsilon_n \quad \forall x \in \Phi_n\right\}
$$

with $\varepsilon_n>0$ and $\Phi_n$ is a finite subset of $E$. Set
$$
D=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \Phi_n,
$$

so that $D$ is countable. We claim that the vector space generated by $D$ is dense in $E$ (which implies that $E$ is separable). Indeed, suppose $f \in E^{\star}$ is such that $\langle f, x\rangle=0 \quad \forall x \in D$. It follows that $f \in V_n \quad \forall n$ and therefore $f \in U_n \quad \forall n$, so that $f=0$.

---

**My question:** I could not see the role of $B_{E^\star}$ in above proof besides the fact that $0 \in B_{E^\star}$. In my "unreal" proof below, I don't use $B_{E^\star}$. Could you elaborate on where I made logical mistakes?

**My attempt:** Fix $g \in E^\star$ such that $g \neq 0$. Let $C := \{0, g\}$. Let $\sigma_C\left(E^{\star}, E\right)$ be the subspace topology on $C$ that is induced from $\sigma\left(E^{\star}, E\right)$.  Because $\sigma\left(E^{\star}, E\right)$ is Hausdorff, we get
$$
\sigma_C\left(E^{\star}, E\right) = \{\emptyset, \{0\}, \{g\}, \{0, g\}\}.
$$

As such, $\sigma_C\left(E^{\star}, E\right)$ is metrizable by a metric $d$ defined on $C$ by $d(g, 0) = 1$. Set
$$
U_n := \left\{f \in C ; d(f, 0)<1 / n\right\}.
$$

Then $U_n$ is an open ball, and thus an open neighborhood (nbh) of $0$ in $\sigma_C\left(E^{\star}, E\right)$. Then there is an open nbh $U'_n$ of $0$ in $\sigma\left(E^{\star}, E\right)$ such that $U_n = U'_n \cap C$. WLOG, $U'_n$ has the form
$$
U'_n=\left\{f \in E^\star ; |\langle f, x\rangle|<\varepsilon_n \quad \forall x \in \Phi_n\right\}.
$$
with $\varepsilon_n>0$ and $\Phi_n$ is a finite subset of $E$. Because $U_n = U'_n \cap C$, we get
$$
U_n=\left\{f \in C ; |\langle f, x\rangle|<\varepsilon_n \quad \forall x \in \Phi_n\right\}.
$$

Set
$$
D=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \Phi_n,
$$
so that $D$ is countable. We claim that the vector space generated by $D$ is dense in $E$ (which implies that $E$ is separable). Indeed, suppose $f \in E^{\star}$ is such that $\langle f, x\rangle=0 \quad \forall x \in D$. It follows that $f \in U_n \quad \forall n$, so that $f=0$.

Comment: There is a very cleaned proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1069320/368425)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the "unreal" proof, I do not think that $f\in U_n$ holds but rather $f\in U_n'$ holds, so you would have to show that $f\in C$ as well to conclude that $f\in U_n$. This does not seem feasible for a general $f$ as belonging to $C$ is pretty restrictive condition.

As for the proof, not only are you using the fact that $0\in B_{E^\star}$ but also the fact that a function being zero can be accurately determined by checking at countable points, as $\cap_n V_n = \{0\}$ and if $f=0$ over $\phi_n$ you guarantee $f\in V_n$. The important concept appears to be that this can be guaranteed by countable $V_n$, or that $0$ has a countable neighbourhood basis, which one can of course conclude easily when the ball is metrizable but may not hold in general spaces.

Comment: I totally agree with the statement [*I do not think that $f\in U_n$ holds but rather $f\in U_n'$ holds*]. Could you have a look at my closely related [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4547080/breziss-proof-of-theorem-3-28-the-existence-of-bounded-in-norm-neighborhood)?